# Is there a way to prevent page flickering/stuttering when scrolling with ScrollTo script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto

I am using [Ariel Flesler's ScrollTo script](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2009/05/jqueryscrollto-142-released.html) on [this page](http://nickputman.com/test/).  I have two links at the bottom of the page that scroll to the top of the page (one also opens a contact form).  I am noticing that at the start of the scroll there is a flickering/stuttering towards the top of the page, and I am wondering if there is anything I can do to prevent this, either by amending the script, or using another scrolling script.  I'd be glad of any advice.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine for me in Chrome, but I see what you mean in Firefox and Internet Explorer.  The problem is caused by the `href="#"` - when you click the link, the browser navigates to the empty hash tag (which will always be the top of the page).

The simplest solution is to prevent the default action of the `<a>` element in its `onclick` handler:

```html
<!-- in the HTML -->
<a id="home-scroll" href="#" onclick="return false;">home</a>
```

```js
// or in your document ready script
$("#home-scroll").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: ... or just remove the `href` all together. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi: that would break the link for users with JS disabled :p

Comment: Probably ;) But I didn't see any code which would have enabled the contact form for users without js, anyway ;)